# Encrypt a string so that even the admin can't figure out

Tags: python, encryption, random, hash, discord

I'm trying to make a Discord confessions bot that maintains partial anonymity of the user. I plan to achieve this by making an embed colour be constant for a user, so people "know" who it is.

The code is open source and the usernames of all server members are all publicly visible, so the name is salted with an environment variable to ensure that nobody can trace the user from their colour. However, since I know the value of the variable, I can technically still figure out which colour belongs to a particular user.

So I was hoping for something pseudo-random-like, but on restarting the program the same "random" number must be generated, but nobody should be able to figure out what it is.

Coming back to my original question. Is it possible to somewhat randomise the algorithm so that even I can't backtrace it to find the colour associated with a user?

I feel like it's not possible, since I want a deterministic algorithm with known possible inputs (small list) and I know the algorithm itself. Like having a list of passwords and the hashing algorithm used.

Code below:

```
import discord
import os
from hashlib import sha256

def embed_text(parsed, user):
  encrypted = sha256((str(user) + os.environ['ENCRYPTION_KEY']).encode()).hexdigest()
  color = int(encrypted[int(encrypted[0],16):int(encrypted[0],16)+6],16)
  return discord.Embed(description=parsed, color=color)
```

Comment: There are lots of one-way function you could use, but since the universe of usernames is rather small, it will never be hard to do a brute-force search to come up with a complete user-to-color mapping.

Comment: On a conceptual point of view, if a machine can do something, its admin can too. This is also said *you cannot trust a machine if you cannot trust its admins*. If you want the server admin not to be able to guess the colour, it means that the colour has to be attributed (and stored) client side.